# Handling multiple records with same ID, inside a foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is an attendance management System, and let me explain how it is structured.
There are two tables here, One is `tbl_temperory` & Other is `tbl_review`,

```
tbl_temperory

Autoid | emp_id | att_date | att_time
-------------------------------------
100    | 05     |05/25/2022| 07.30
101    | 05     |05/25/2022| 09.30
102    | 05     |05/25/2022| 18.30
103    | 06     |05/25/2022| 08.30
104    | 06     |05/25/2022| 20.30

tbl_review

Autoid | emp_id | att_date | clock_in | clock_out
-------------------------------------------------
200    | 05     |05/25/2022| 18.30    |
201    | 06     |05/25/2022| 08.30    | 20.30
```

When the user clocked in or clocked out initial record updates to the temporary table, sometimes the user can clock in and clock out multiple times, So the Temporary table might have multiple records for the same user.

During Day End there is a option to fetch the Attendance Record, and it updates to `tbl_review`.

Now the problem here is, When there is only two records for an employee, `tbl_review` updates the `clock_in` & `clock_out` percfectly. But when there is multiple Records, it updates only the last record time as `clock_in` time.

I have below attached the foreach loop how it updates the review table, Can someone guide me, where I am making the Mistake.

Thank you.

```
$temp = All records from temp table Stored here
 if ($temp) { 
   $i = 0;
   $employee = '';
   $continue = FALSE;
   foreach ($temp as $row) {
    if ($continue) {   
      $continue = FALSE;
      $i++;
      continue;
    }
    $employee = $row['emp_id'];
    $attendanceDate = $row['att_date'];
    $clockIn = $row['att_time'];
    $nextKey = $i + 1;
    $clockOut = NULL;
     if (array_key_exists($nextKey, $temp)) {
        if ($temp[$nextKey]['emp_id'] == $row['emp_id'] && $attendanceDate == $temp[$nextKey]['att_date']) {
                    $clockOut = $temp[$nextKey]['att_time'];
                    $continue = TRUE;
                }

    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: When you handle the first record, it finds the next record, fill in both `clockIn` and `clockOut`, then skip the second record. Then it comes across the third record of the same day, now that there is no next record, it then overwrite the `clockIn` with the third time, and overwrite `clockOut` with `NULL`.

Comment: Instead of find and skip the next record, better loop through the temp records one by one without skipping, fill in `clockIn` if `clockIn` of that day is `NULL`, if `clockIn` is not `NULL`, then update `clockOut` instead.

Comment: @RickyMo Yes, Your Second point is considerable and tried, Here if there is five or six records for an employee, first and second record updates as clock in and clock out, actually sixth record should pass as clock out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can do this with a single insert query. The `clock_in` time for a user/employee will be the least punch time among all and `clock_out` will be the maximum of them all for a given date.

So, you can construct a query with [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and inject the current date at hand via prepared statements into the below query:

```
insert into tbl_review(emp_id, att_date,clock_in, clock_out) 
SELECT emp_id, att_date , min(STR_TO_DATE(att_time, '%H.%i:%s')) as clock_in, max(STR_TO_DATE(att_time, '%H.%i:%s')) as clock_out
FROM `tbl_temperory`
where att_date = '05/25/2022' -- your date variable here
group by emp_id
```

Comment: Thank you, By the way I want to handle this on PHP, not in SQL

Comment: @KhnRzk What's the point of that when you can do this with a single query? Our aim is to insert rows for that day, ain't it?

Comment: I am trying this Query Modification, But clock in and clock out returns Null

Comment: @KhnRzk I tested it on my system and it works perfectly fine. Can you share a db fiddle of your issue?

Comment: min & max function working without STR_TO_DATE

Comment: @KhnRzk That's great but I would still recommend casting them for the min and max calculations, just to be sure.

Comment: STR_TO_DATE not getting 24 hours time format I guess

Comment: @KhnRzk It sure does. I assume your time format is `HH.mm`. Correct?

Comment: its `HH.mm:ss` 24 hours format

Comment: @KhnRzk The seconds was missing in your question. I will update, give me 2 mins

Comment: @KhnRzk Do you use MariaDB ?

Comment: Yes MariaDB is used

Comment: @KhnRzk Ok, I updated my answer for the seconds in time as well with that extra `:%s`. It works fine on my machine as shown in this image https://ibb.co/0r3YyDX

Comment: For, Above didn't work, but `%T` worked

Comment: @KhnRzk That's great. I presume this has something to do with version difference of your Maria DB version and mine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245018/discussion-between-nice-dev-and-khn-rzk).

Answer (score 1):

With similar logic to your codes, assuming that your records are simillar to the one you shows (ascending emp_id and att_time).

```
if ($temp) {
    $i = 0;
    $newID = TRUE;
    foreach ($temp as $row) {
        $employee = $row['emp_id'];
        $attendanceDate = $row['att_date'];
        $nextKey = $i + 1;
        
        if ($newID) {
            $clockIn = $row['att_time'];
            addClockInToTblReview($employee, $attendanceDate, $clockIn);
        }
        
        if (array_key_exists($nextKey, $temp)) {
            if ($temp[$nextKey]['emp_id'] != $row['emp_id'] || $attendanceDate != $temp[$nextKey]['att_date']) {
                $clockOut = $row['att_time'];
                addClockOutToTblReview($employee, $attendanceDate, $clockOut);
                $newID = TRUE;
            } else {
                $newID = FALSE;
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

The logic is to iterate every data entry,

- if its the first entry with the same id and date, update clockIn
- if next data entry is with a different id or different date, update clockOut
- else do nothing and continue

ps. write your own `addClockInToTblReview` and `addClockOutToTblReview` as not much info regarding the db is provided

Comment: Thank you for your effort, by the way I got a solution from above marked answer :)